# My custom css changes don’t work until I add "html" to the beginning of each line

Tags: css

I’m new to Bootstrap. Using version 3.

I’m using a "custom.css" file to customize the design of my website.

The problem I’m seeing is that none of my customizations work unless I put "html" at the beginning of the relevant line.

When I put html at the beginning of a line, the change does take effect, so I know the file is working.

Can anyone help with this? I’ve used custom css files before, and I’ve never seen this before.

Comment: It would be useful if you share your code. It seems could be an unclosed tag

Comment: Sorry no one can help you until you share some piece of code...... Otherwise your question will be closed....

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

you have to import CSS file to correct location at HTML file also please share your code for find solution quickly